# What are the algorithms to calculate shortest routes in a bi-direction graphic?

Tags: algorithms, graph-theory

If I have a graphic

$A\rightarrow B$ weight $10$
$B\rightarrow A\qquad   11$ 
$B\rightarrow C\qquad   20$ 
$C\rightarrow D\qquad  5$
$D\rightarrow C\qquad  16$
$D\rightarrow B\qquad  9$
$D\rightarrow A\qquad  7$

then, if start from any one of the node, I want to know the shortest path to another.
Does anyone what kind of algorithms can do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Dijkstra's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on what sort of solution you need. If you absolutely need a global one regardless of the time needed, use Dynamic programming. If you are happy with a local one, any sort of heuristic algorithms would do (e.g. Evolutionary Algorithms, Simulated Annealing, etc)